# Are there or have there been Christian healing ministries that have documented healing cases with supporting medical records?

Tags: history, resource-request, healing, healthcare, faith-healing

Christian healing ministries abound. A quick search on any search engine can lead to lots of ministries that claim to be able to heal the sick, as well as testimonials of people who claim to have received healing of some ailment during a healing crusade, or because someone prayed for them, etc. I'm not questioning the sincerity of all people nor claiming that everyone is lying, on the contrary, I truly believe that a significant percentage of the testimonies out there must be genuine, in the sense that people are telling the truth when they share their personal experiences of healing.

That said, I'm still curious to know if any Christian healing ministry out there has undertaken the effort of documenting at least some of their healings, by keeping copies of the medical records of the healed person and the results of a subsequent medical examination confirming that the person is completely healed. Has a Christian healing ministry ever done that?

---

Responding to concerns raised in the comments:

By healing ministry I mean either an individual or a group of people who claim to have the gift of healing or to have been called by God to heal the sick as an active occupation. However, for the sake of getting answers, other medically documented cases of healing occurred in similar circumstances are acceptable too, such as:

- A holy place where people are commonly reported to get miraculously healed.
- Someone who gets prayed for (and healed) by someone else and has the medical records to prove it (in this case the healed person is the one with the evidence, not the healing ministry, but that's fine).
- And any other situation that is close to what I'm looking for that I may be overlooking.

Comment: Hospitals don't tend to record "prayer" as a treatment, so what you end up with is an entry in the medial record saying "this person has a tumour" followed a few days later saying "further imaging revealed no tumour", and something to the effect that there might have been an imaging error in the initial diagnosis or that the symptoms vanished for no known reason.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "healing ministry".  If you would count a holy site, then Lourdes is probably the best place to start.  I believe they have quite a few records of documented cures.  How to access their records, I don't know.

Comment: @workerjoe - good point, I forgot about that corner case. Yes, I'm willing to accept an answer that expands the concept to include a holy place where people commonly get healed, as long as those healings are documented with supporting medical records.

Comment: Also, Catholic beatification and canonization require evidence of miraculous interventions, which are usually healing miracles and which must be documented by medical professionals. But in not sure how available those records are to the public.

Comment: There is a distinction to be made between documented and then publishing that information.

Comment: I know a man who had a diagnosed detached retina.  After much prayer, on his follow-up visit, the retina had somehow re-attached.  The doctor had no explanation.  There is no official documentation.  I suspect the vast majority of miracles are such.  My experience is much the same.  Good question, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are there or have there been Christian healing ministries that have documented healing cases with supporting medical records?**

The Catholic Church has a long tradition of accepting medical miracles as miraculous only after a lengthy investigation into the matter. Although the miraculous are now well documented, the files are generally not published for public viewing. There is a distinction to be made between documented and then publishing that information.

The miraculous healing in the Catholic Church need to be **spontaneous, instantaneous and complete healing**. Medical doctors have to be able say “We don't have any natural explanation of what happened."
I would like to point out that those doing the scientific and/or medical investigations do not necessarily have to be Catholic.

I am going to answer this in a rather unique manner and probably one not intended, yet would qualify as an example, while not being interpreted in the normal thought of what a modern healing ministry seems to mean.

I am talking about [***The Healing Ministry of Mary***](https://beingisgood.blogspot.com/2011/11/morning-of-reflection-healing-ministry.html).

The healing ability of Mary goes down several centuries and is continuing in our own times.

I am going to make a double biblical metaphor here, if you will allow me to do so.

I am going to use the metaphor of Mary, the Mother of Jesus as the [Pool of Bethsaida](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_of_Bethesda) which goes well with the imagery of the healing apparitions of Mary at [Lourdes as a place of healing](https://www.lourdes-france.org/en/lourdes-place-of-healing/).

> 1 After this came a Jewish feast, for which Jesus went up to Jerusalem. 2 There is a pool in Jerusalem at the Sheep Gate, called in Hebrew Bethsaida, with five porches, 3 under which a multitude of diseased folk used to lie, the blind, the lame, the disabled, waiting for a disturbance of the water. 4 From time to time, an angel of the Lord came down upon the pool, and the water was stirred up; and the first man who stepped into the pool after the stirring of the water, recovered from whatever infirmity it was that oppressed him. 5 There was one man there who had been disabled for thirty-eight years. 6 Jesus saw him lying there, and knew that he had waited a long time; Hast thou a mind, he asked, to recover thy strength? 7 Sir, said the cripple, I have no one to let me down into the pool when the water is stirred; and while I am on my way, somebody else steps down before me. 8 Jesus said to him, Rise up, take up thy bed, and walk. 9 And all at once the man recovered his strength, and took up his bed, and walked. That day it was the sabbath: 10 and the Jews said to the man who had been cured, It is the sabbath; it is not lawful for thee to carry thy bed. 11 He answered them, The man who gave me back my strength told me himself, Take up thy bed, and walk. 12 So they asked him, Who is this man who told thee, Take up thy bed, and walk? 13 The cripple who had been healed did not know who it was; Jesus had drawn aside from so crowded a place. 14 But afterwards when Jesus found him in the temple, and said to him, Behold, thou hast recovered thy strength; do not sin any more, for fear that worse should befall thee, 15 the man went back and told the Jews that it was Jesus who had restored his strength. - [John 5:1-14](https://www.newadvent.org/bible/joh005.htm#vrs3)

Lourdes resembles the Pool of Bethsaida in the sense that those seeking physical healing bath in the waters.

Lourdes water is water which flows from a spring in the Grotto of Massabielle in the Sanctuary of Our Lady of Lourdes, France. The location of the spring was described to Bernadette Soubirous by an apparition of Our Lady of Lourdes on 25 February 1858. Since that time, many thousands of pilgrims to Lourdes have followed the instruction of **Our Lady of Lourdes to "drink at the spring and bathe in it".** Lourdes water is considered non-liturgical holy water.

> The Sanctuary of Our Lady of Lourdes or the Domain (as it is most commonly known) is an area of ground surrounding the Catholic shrine (Grotto) to Our Lady of Lourdes in the town of Lourdes, France. The Sanctuary is a destination for pilgrimage; sick pilgrims are reputed to be miraculously healed by Lourdes water. This ground is owned and administered by the Roman Catholic Church, and has several functions, including devotional activities, offices, and accommodation for sick pilgrims and their helpers. The Domain includes the Grotto itself, the nearby taps which dispense the Lourdes water, and the offices of the Lourdes Medical Bureau, as well as several churches and basilicas. It comprises an area of 51 hectares, and includes 22 separate places of worship. There are six official languages of the Sanctuary: French, English, Italian, Spanish, Dutch and German.
>
> Lourdes water flows from a spring at the same spot where it was discovered by Bernadette. The original spring can be seen within the Grotto, lit from below and protected by a glass screen. Pilgrims drink Lourdes water due to its reputed healing power. The water is accessed from individual taps located between the grotto and the baths, The water from Lourdes was thoroughly analysed by independent chemists in 1858 and 1859, and does not appear to have a latent power to cure and has no special scientific or medicinal properties. Despite this, the water is itself a strong symbol of devotion for Lourdes pilgrims, and many buy statues and rosary beads containing small vials of it, and take home large plastic containers of it.
>
> **Baths**
>
> Each year about 350,000 pilgrims bathe in the water at the baths (Piscines).[5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012&version=DRA) During the pilgrimage season, the baths are open 8:30 am –12:30 pm / 1:30 – 6:00 pm on weekdays and 10.00 am-12.00 noon / 2.00 pm-4.00 pm Sundays and Holidays. - [Sanctuary of Our Lady of Lourdes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_of_Our_Lady_of_Lourdes)

Mary is still healing people at Lourdes and the latest confirmed miracle on February 12, 2018.

> Lourdes, France, Feb 12, 2018 / 02:00 pm MT ().- A miracle was officially recognized at the Marian shrine of Our Lady of Lourdes in France, the 70th Lourdes miracle recognized by the Catholic Church.
>
> The miraculous event involved a French nun, Sister Bernadette Moriau, who went on a pilgrimage to the shrine of Our Lady of Lourdes in 2008. She had been suffering from spinal complications which had rendered her wheelchair-bound and fully disabled since 1980. She also said she had been taking morphine to control the pain.
>
> Moriau’s case was brought to the attention of the International Medical Committee of Lourdes, who extensively researched the nun’s recovery. They eventually found that Moriau’s healing could not be scientifically explained.
>
> After a healing is recognized by the Lourdes committee, the paperwork is then sent to the diocese of origin, where the local bishop has the final say. After the bishop’s blessing, a healing can then be officially recognized by the Church as a miracle. - [The 70th miracle: Lourdes healing officially declared supernatural](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/its-a-miracle-lourdes-healing-officially-declared-supernatural-84194)

***Of the 70,000 alleged miracles at Lourdes only 70 miracles (as of 2018) have been approved as worthy of belief.*** [The Cures at Lourdes which have been recognised as miraculous by the Church](http://www.miraclehunter.com/marian_apparitions/approved_apparitions/lourdes/downloads/lourdes_cures.pdf).

**The second metaphor** I will be using is taking the [Woman of the Apocalypse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman_of_the_Apocalypse) and the apparitions at Fátima and the Miracle of the Sun.

> 12 And a great sign appeared in heaven: A woman clothed with the sun, and the moon under her feet, and on her head a crown of twelve stars:
>
> 2 And being with child, she cried travailing in birth, and was in pain to be delivered.
>
> 3 And there was seen another sign in heaven: and behold a great red dragon, having seven heads, and ten horns: and on his head seven diadems:
>
> 4 And his tail drew the third part of the stars of heaven, and cast them to the earth: and the dragon stood before the woman who was ready to be delivered; that, when she should be delivered, he might devour her son.
>
> 5 And she brought forth a man child, who was to rule all nations with an iron rod: and her son was taken up to God, and to his throne.
>
> 6 And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she had a place prepared by God, that there they should feed her a thousand two hundred sixty days.
>
> 7 And there was a great battle in heaven, Michael and his angels fought with the dragon, and the dragon fought and his angels:
>
> 8 And they prevailed not, neither was their place found any more in heaven.
>
> 9 And that great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, who is called the devil and Satan, who seduceth the whole world; and he was cast unto the earth, and his angels were thrown down with him.
>
> 10 And I heard a loud voice in heaven, saying: Now is come salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: because the accuser of our brethren is cast forth, who accused them before our God day and night.
>
> 11 And they overcame him by the blood of the Lamb, and by the word of the testimony, and they loved not their lives unto death.
>
> 12 Therefore rejoice, O heavens, and you that dwell therein. Woe to the earth, and to the sea, because the devil is come down unto you, having great wrath, knowing that he hath but a short time.
>
> 13 And when the dragon saw that he was cast unto the earth, he persecuted the woman, who brought forth the man child:
>
> 14 And there were given to the woman two wings of a great eagle, that she might fly into the desert unto her place, where she is nourished for a time and times, and half a time, from the face of the serpent.
>
> 15 And the serpent cast out of his mouth after the woman, water as it were a river; that he might cause her to be carried away by the river.
>
> 16 And the earth helped the woman, and the earth opened her mouth, and swallowed up the river, which the dragon cast out of his mouth.
>
> 17 And the dragon was angry against the woman: and went to make war with the rest of her seed, who keep the commandments of God, and have the testimony of Jesus Christ.
>
> 18 And he stood upon the sand of the sea. - [Revelation 12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012&version=DRA)

It is easily seen as to how the Mary can be compared to the ***Woman of the Apocalypse*** with the Marian apparitions at Fátima and the [Miracle of the Sun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_Sun).

> On the 13th day of the month, from May to October 1917, the Blessed Virgin Mary appeared to Lucia, Francisco, and Jacinta, who were ten, nine, and seven years old. Through these humble and simple children, Heaven provided Earth a warning of dangers to come that could lead to the destruction of the world and the ruin of countless souls. In a prophetic secret, Our Lady gave the children a frightening vision of Hell, and foretold the coming of the Second World War, the rise of Communist Russia, and the persecution of the Church. To draw the world from this ruinous course and to bring about a lasting peace, she called for the Rosary to be prayed daily, for acts of penance, and for the consecration of Russia to her Immaculate Heart. With these dire warnings and urgent requests, the Mother of God also gave a promise of hope: “In the end, my Immaculate Heart will triumph.”

All of this was reported by the shepherd children. The message of Fatima—without any propaganda or publicity—spread by word of mouth and crossed the frontiers of Portugal. The irresistible flow of pilgrims increased more and more in response to this message of hope. **During the last apparition, on October 13, 1917, a crowd of 70,000 gathered at the Cova da Iria, where Our Lady had appeared to the children.** She promised a great miracle that day so all would believe. As the crowds raised their eyes to Heaven in prayer, they would witness the promised miracle, confirming everything the children had said. They saw the sun dance.

> Then the sun began to dance, whirling violently through the sky, shooting forth streams of light which colored objects on the ground. The sun then seemed to detach itself from the sky and plummet to the Earth. Another witness, Maria Carreira, recalled: “It looked like a wheel of fire that was going to fall on the people. They began to cry out, ‘We shall all be killed!’ Others called to Our Lady to save them. They recited acts of contrition. One woman began to confess her sins aloud, advertising that she had done this and that…” (quoted in Fatima for Today). The sun then climbed back to its normal place in the sky, leaving everything instantaneously dry, from the dirt on the ground to the clothes on the people’s backs. The whole spectacle lasted about 10 minutes.
>
> Not every witness was a willing believer. Many were skeptics, and some were even declared enemies of the Church.
>
> Not every witness was in Fatima either. The great miracle was seen by many people from neighboring towns and villages up to 25 miles away. These distant witnesses dispel theories of mass hallucination or suggestion resulting from the heightened emotion of expectation. - [Hope and mercy and the “Miracle of the Sun”](https://www.catholicworldreport.com/2017/10/13/hope-and-mercy-and-the-miracle-of-the-sun/)

When Lúcia (one of the seers) was asked why God healed so few people, she simply replied: “God knows the hearts of men. He is leery of man!”

Nevertheless, some medical miracles at Fátima have been approved by the Church.

Here are a couple of examples of Mary working miracles at Fátima, Portugal.

> Our Lady's apparitions at Fatima ended October 13th 1917 with the spin of the solar disk for ten minutes in front of over fifty thousand people. Then the great sanctuary was built; celebrations started, and the hand of God revealed itself, especially through the miraculous events. We name a few, among the most significant.
>
> **Healing from cancer**
>
> Joaquim Duarte Oliveira, residing in Lisbon, got cancer,he had been lying in bed for eight years. He had received all possible care from the best specialists in Portugal, but but with no results. His wife, as a last resort, in October 1927, entrusted herself to Our Lady of Fatima to whom she made a promise; she administered to her husband, without his knowledge, a few drops of the prodigious water. On his pillow she would leave the edition "Voice of Fatima" where stories were told about the miraculous cure of Dr. Agacio Ribeiro. Joaquim, driven by curiosity began to read. By reading he felt the faith and hope in the Virgin. Unexpectedly, he began to pray to Our Lady of Fatima to heal him, as she had cured the doctor. Just at that moment he felt entirely transformed, totally healed, and the next day Joaquim resumed his normal life. A month later he went with his family to Fatima to thank the Virgin Mary.
>
> **Extraordinary healing**
>
> Emilia Martins 42 years, a native of Santiago,had beeb lying in bed for six years, she could hardly move around and her stomach did not tolerate any food. Woman of great faith she wanted to go to Fatima, but could not because she was too poor. Some devout people gathered the amount necessary to rent a car and so Emilia went with a nurse and two sisters. During the journey, her condition worsened and in Oporto Emilia was administered the last rites, but was able to resume her journey. When she arrived to the Sanctuary, she was brought on a stretcher to the hospital, while in the hospital underwent several syncopes, in one of which a doctor said, "She is dead." The insistence of one of the assistants, revealed a few heartbeats, it was decided to bring her to the Blessing of the sick. The sick woman, upon receiving the blessing, awoke as from sleep, opened her eyes and perked up little by little, finally she regained consciousness. She felt a general well-being and exclaimed: "I am healed" ... "May Our Lady of Fatima be praised and thanked". The doctor gave a certificate of full recovery, in which he declared that the fact had occurred so suddenly that the case was not medically explainable. - [Fatima](https://digilander.libero.it/rexur/miracol/inglese/fatima.htm)

Many are the miracles of the ***Healing Ministry of Mary***.

In a [Ripley's Believe It or Not](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripley%27s_Believe_It_or_Not!) moment, some would call restoring someone’s tongue, while others would like to denied it as fact.

> On the left side of the Shrine of Our Lady of Oropa, there are three marble gravestones with inscriptions in Latin which refer to the three miracles **legally recognized by the Ecclesiastical Authority and authenticated by regular canonical process.** They are:
>
> **John the Baptist Perrone**
>
> John the Baptist Perrone in 1718 was taken prisoner by the Turks, who urged him to renounce the Catholic faith, he refused and his tongue was cut off. The Franciscans and rescued him so he could return to Piedmont. He came to Oropa for the coronation of Mary Healer of Oropa and obtained the grace: the instant the bishop Gattinara, Bishop of Alexandria, set down on the head of the Virgin the new tiara, he felt his tongue growing and recovered the ability to speak. As in the previous case, a canonical trial was started and ended in the year 1724 by approving as miracle "the recovery of tongue and speech by John Perrone.". - [Miracles at Oropa](https://digilander.libero.it/rexur/miracol/inglese/oropa.htm)

And then there was Padre Pio!

[image]

> [The Most Amazing Case of Padre Pio’s Intercession?](http://thepathlesstaken7.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-most-amazing-case-of-padre-pios.html)
>
> The case of Gemma di Giorgi baffles doctors. Born in the Sicilian town of Ribera on Christmas day, 1939, her mother noted that Gemma seemed different to other children.
>
> Looking into the eyes of her little girl, Gemma’s mother noticed that her eyes seemed abnormal and malformed. Gemma’s mother took her to doctor after doctor, and they diagnosed that she had no pupils, and that there was no medicines or surgery that would cure her.  Her parents concluded that they would have to pray for a miracle, they had a relation who was a nun and she recommended that they get in touch with Padre Pio. Gemma’s grandmother entreated the nun to send a letter to Padre Pio on behalf of her blind granddaughter.
>
> After sending the letter, the nun had a dream where Padre Pio appeared to her and asked her, "where is Gemma for whom so many prayers are being offered that they are almost deafening?"
>
> In the dream, the nun presented Gemma to Padre Pio and he made the sign of the cross over her eyes. The very next day, a letter arrived from Padre Pio. He wrote, "Dear daughter, rest assured that I will pray for Gemma. I send you my best wishes."
> The ‘coincidence’ of the dream and the letter coming one after the other – stunned the nun who contacted Gemma’s family and persuaded them to take Gemma to see Padre Pio.
>
> In 1947, Gemma and her grandmother set off for San Giovanni Rotondo. Gemma was 7 at the time.  While they were on the way, mysteriously, inexplicably and unexpectedly, Gemma began to see…she could see the sea and a ship. When she told her grandmother, she took this as a sign and began to pray.
>
> A miracle had clearly taken place, but Gemma’s grandmother was still under the impression that they needed to ask Padre Pio’s intercession, and to do so in person. When their journey ended and they reached San Giovanni Rotondo, Padre Pio saw Gemma approach, and said hello to her.  He had never been introduced in ‘real life’ to Gemma, but knew who she was, the minute he clapped eyes on her.
>
> The little seven-year-old Gemma entered the dark confines of Padre Pio’s confessional. Contrary to her grandmother’s wishes, Gemma never said anything of her eyes to Padre Pio, but he touched her eyes with the bloody part of his hand, and drew the sign of the cross on her.
>
> Gemma’s grandmother was disappointed and emotional that Gemma had neglected to ask of Padre Pio a grace for healing her eyes.  Tears streamed down her face, and so she went to confession to Padre Pio, and asked him to intercede on Gemma's behalf and said, "I asked the grace for Gemma and I told Padre Pio that Gemma was weeping because, in her confession with him she had forgotten to ask this grace. I will never forget his soft and tender voice as he answered me with these words, "Do you have faith, my daughter? The child must not weep and neither must you for the child sees, and you know she sees." I understood then that Padre Pio was alluding to the sea and the ship Gemma had seen during the trip and that God had used Padre Pio to break through the darkness that covered Gemma's eyes."

[image]

Comment: Ken you can't make these amazingly substantive answers so long :) good response!

Answer (score 1):

**Are there or have there been Christian, non-Catholic, healing ministries that have documented healing cases with supporting medical records?**

There seem to be a few, but the rigorous are not to the same standards of those of the Catholic Church.

One such person is the American evangelist who healed several persons of various ailments.

Kathryn Kuhlman was an American evangelist known for hosting healing services. Her miraculous healings are well documented, although not at the same level as that of the Catholic Church, they nevertheless quite well documented and are credible by many.

> [Kathryn Johanna Kuhlman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathryn_Kuhlman) was born near Concordia, Missouri, to German-American parents, Joseph Adolph Kuhlman and Emma Walkenhorst. After a spiritual experience at age 14, several years later, she began itinerant preaching, with her elder sister and brother-in law, in Idaho. Later, she was ordained by the Evangelical Church Alliance.
>
> Kuhlman met Burroughs Waltrip, a Texas evangelist who was eight years her senior. Shortly after his visit to Denver, Waltrip divorced his wife, left his family and moved to Mason City, Iowa, where he began a revival center called Radio Chapel. Kuhlman and her friend and pianist Helen Gulliford came into town to help him raise funds for his ministry. It was shortly after their arrival that the romance between Burroughs and Kuhlman became publicly known.
>
> **Ministry**
>
> Kuhlman traveled extensively around the United States and in many other countries holding "healing crusades" between the 1940s and 1970s. She was one of the most well-known healing ministers in the world. Kuhlman had a weekly TV program in the 1960s and 1970s called I Believe In Miracles that was aired nationally. She also had a 30-minute nationwide radio ministry of teaching from the Bible and frequently would feature excerpts from her healing services (both music and message). Her foundation was established in 1954, and its Canadian branch in 1970. Late in her life she was supportive of the nascent Jesus movement, and received endorsements by its key leaders, including David Wilkerson and Chuck Smith.
>
> By 1970 she moved to Los Angeles, conducting healing services for thousands of people, and was often compared to Aimee Semple MacPherson. She became well known for her "gift of healing" despite, as she often noted, having no theological training. She was friendly with Christian television pioneer Pat Robertson and made guest appearances at his Christian Broadcasting Network (CBN) and on the network's flagship program The 700 Club.
>
> **Healing**
>
> Many accounts of medically documented healings were published in her books, which were written by author Jamie Buckingham of Florida, including her autobiography, which was dictated at a hotel in Las Vegas. Buckingham also wrote his own Kuhlman biography that presented an unvarnished account of her life. An estimated two million people reported they were healed in her meetings over the years.
>
> Following a 1967 fellowship in Philadelphia, Dr. William A. Nolen conducted a case study of 23 people who said they had been cured during one of her services.[13][14][15][16] Nolen's long term follow-ups concluded that there were no cures in those cases. One woman who was said to have been cured of spinal cancer threw away her brace and ran across the stage at Kuhlman's command; her spine collapsed the next day and she died four months later.
>
> Nolen's analysis of Kulhman came in for criticism from believers. Lawrence Althouse, a physician, said that Nolen had attended only one of Kuhlman's services and did not follow up with all of those who said they had been healed there. Dr. Richard Casdorph produced a book of evidence in support of miraculous healings by Kuhlman. Hendrik van der Breggen, a Christian philosophy professor, argued in favor of the claims. Author Craig Keener concluded, "No one claims that everyone was healed, but it is also difficult to dispute that significant recoveries occurred, apparently in conjunction with prayer. One may associate these with Kathryn Kuhlman's faith or that of the supplicants, or, as in some of Kuhlman's teaching, to no one's faith at all; but the evidence suggests that some people were healed, even in extraordinary ways."
>
> Dr. Richard Owellen, a member of the cancer‐research department of the Johns Hopkins Hospital who appeared frequently at Miss Kuhlman's services, testified to various healings that he said he had investigated.

Some of her medical miracles have been noted and documented reasonably quite well.

> **“Protestant" Miracles: Good medical evidence**
>
> I call this section "Protestant" not because Protestants are necessarily involved in all of these examples, in face some may involve Catholics, but because most of them do not have the rigor or backing of the Catholic miracle machinery. Some of them are actually scientifically rigorous, but even those don't have the same sort of rigor of the Catholic miracles, and some are merely anecdotal. But we can learn something from all examples, even the bad ones. Mainly what we learn is that there are tons of miracle claims still being made all the time. Just because most of them are not well documented does not mean that many of them are not actual miracles. Most people are not prepared to document the amazing things that happen to them. When one's loved one is stricken down, and than by some amazing stroke that loved one is restored, totally unexpectedly, the last thing one thinks of is documenting what happened. It is with this realization that I present the following cases.
>
> **1) Reticulum cell Sarcoma, right pelvic bone.**
>
> **2) Chronic Rheumatoid Arthritis with Severe Disability**
>
> **3) Malignant Brain Tumor (Glioma) of the left Temporal lobe**
>
> **4) Multiple Sclerosis**
>
> **5) Arteriosclerosis Heart Disease**
>
> **6) Carcinoma of the Kidney (Hypernephroma)**
>
> **7) Mixed Rheumatoid Arthritis with Osteoarthritis**
>
> **8) Probable Brain Tumor vs Infarction of the Brain**
>
> **9) Massive GI Hemorrhage with GI shock (instantly healed)**
>
> **10) Osteoporosis of the Entire Spine**
>
> All of these people were totally healed of incurable or terminal states. The one commonality they all have is that they were at some point prayed for by the same person, Kuhlman. Let's look at a few examples:
>
> **1) Lisa Larios: Cell Sarcoma of the right Pelvic bone.**
>
> Larios didn't know she had cancer. She had developed a great deal of pain in her pelvis and was confined to a wheel chair, but the doctors had not found the evidence of the tumor at the time her mother took her to hear Kuhlman. Yet, when Miss Kuhlman said "someone over here is being healed of cancer, please stand up" she stood up without knowing why. She had already started feeling a strange heat in that area and had ceased to feel pain. She went up onto the stage and walked around without pain. She was than "slain in the spirit" which is that odd thing when the healer places his/her hand on the forehead and the person falls over in a faint. It took some time to receive the next set of x-rays because she only learned after the meeting some days latter that she had cancer. Than the next set of x-rays showed vast and dramatic improvement. It would still be some time, almost a year, before her pelvis was completely resorted. But she did return to full health. The Catholics wouldn't except this miracle because it could be confused with a normal remission. The power of suggestion can be ruled out because the heat started before she was called to the stage, and because she didn't even know she had cancer, but responded to a call for healing of cancer. The first dramatic improvement which was immediate within a few days, and walking on the stage is not characteristic of remission. Casdorph has the medical evidence from several hospitals to which she had been taken.
>
> **3) Mrs. Marie Rosenberger: Malignant Brain Tumor.**
>
> "Three things make this case an exceptionally excellent example of divine healing. 1) medical evidence of the case includes biopsy proof of the malignant nature of the tumor. The slides were obtained from Hollywood community Hospital and reviewed by the head pathologist at Long Beach community Hospital who confirmed the diagnosis of malignant astrocytoma or glioma class II. 2) When the healing occurred Marie Rosenberger was down to 101 pounds and was expected to die."
>
> The healing began to manifest immediately and by the next morning was evident. She received no further drugs or medication from that point on. 3) The third thing that makes the case good is the long term nature of the healing. Her diagnosis was in 1970 and by the time Casdorph wrote the book in 76 she was still healthy and happy with no sign of the disease since the healing (which was in 1971 one year after the diagnosis) .
>
> **8) Anne Soults: Probable brain tumor vs. Infarction of the brain.**
>
> "This lady's brain abnormality was well documented by the standard diagnostic techniques and she was seen by man specialists. Electroencephalographic study was performed in each of her hospitalizations. The repeat study dated January 6th reported 'abnormal EEG suggesting left temporary pathology, there is no significant change since 12/27/74.'...the clinical impression was that of brain tumor and her symptoms suddenly and completely disappeared following a visit to the Shrine service."
>
> When she went to the service an unknown Christian placed his hands on her shoulders and prayed for her. The symptoms immediately disappeared and subsequent tests found that the abnormality had disappeared. This is not normal remission. Remission does not mean that the symptoms immediately vanish.
>
> **9) Paul Wittney Trousdale: Massive GI Hemorrhage.**
>
> Trousdale was a prominent civic leader and builder in California in the early 70s. On December 12, 1973 he was admitted to St. John's Hospital in Santa Monica with massive hemorrhaging which required many transfusions. His wife called Reverend John Hinkle to his bedside, they prayed and he was instantly healed. All the medical values returned to normal and he went on to live a normal and productive life, engaging in athletics and sports. Subsequent examinations revealed no abnormalities.
>
> **10) Delores Winder: Osteoporosis of the Complete Spine.**
>
> "Mrs. Delores Winder presents us with an unusual case of severe, chronic, disabling pain secondary to Osteoporosis, which her physicians tried to relieve by five different spine operations. The patients symptoms had begun early in 1957. By 1962 she had worn a full body cast or brace of some sort... although at the time of her healing she was in a light weight full body plastic shell. Although she did not believe in instant miraculous healing she attended a lecture by Miss Kuhlman in Dallas on August 30. 1975.She was miraculously healed beginning with a sensation of heat in both of her lower extremities. She has been resorted to full health, wears no brace or support, takes no medication and has completely normal sensations in the lower extremities. This is unusual because the spinathalamic in the spinal cord had been interrupted on both sides, and in such cases the resulting numbness is usually permanent."
>
> **Time Magazine Article**
>
> Time Magazine did an article on Miracles and Nancy Biggs documented several examples which are backed by medical evidence. Some where anecdotal accounts, but at least she interviewed the principles. While she doesn't document the crucial medical evidence such as doctor's names, nor does she interview the doctors, the fact of medical diagnosis is at least present.
>
> [Scientific Evidence of Miracles 5](http://god-and-science.com/gsi/doxa/god/args/38_miracles5.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a Latter-day Saint perspective on this one--I don't consider myself qualified to speak to the views of other faiths on this topic and don't want to misrepresent what someone else believes.

**Doctrinal Background**

> 5 We believe that a man must be called of God, by prophecy, and by the
> laying on of hands by those who are in authority, to preach the Gospel
> and administer in the ordinances thereof.
>
> 7 We believe in the gift of tongues, prophecy, revelation, visions,
> healing, interpretation of tongues, and so forth. (Articles of Faith 1:5,7)

> [H]as the day of miracles ceased? Or have angels ceased to appear unto
> the children of men? Or has he withheld the power of the Holy Ghost
> from them? Or will he, so long as time shall last, or the earth shall
> stand, or there shall be one man upon the face thereof to be saved?
> Behold I say unto you, Nay; (Moroni 7:35-37)

Latter-day Saints believe in a restoration in modern times of the same priesthood authority held anciently by the apostles, and believe that miracles are performed.

Generally, Latter-day Saints do not draw a great deal of public attention to miraculous healings; the experiences are often considered personal and sacred. The Savior Himself often asked those He healed not to make a big public statement. So if the question seeks for hospital discharge papers that say "miracle", there won't be so much information to collect. But if the presence of people with medical experience is adequate for purposes of the OP's question, the examples below will probably be in scope.

--

**Joseph Smith and the malaria outbreak in Nauvoo**

When members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints were expelled from the state of Missouri in 1838, the largest group settled along the Mississippi River in Illinois, where the presence of malaria-bearing mosquitoes led to a significant outbreak.

On July 22, 1839, the Prophet Joseph Smith travelled throughout the settlements and healed numerous people afflicted with malaria. This was done in the presence of many witnesses and was referred to by some as "A Day of God's Power".

See documentation in [this journal article](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1414&context=re) (pp. 7-8) and in [this historical summary](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/history/saints-v1/34-build-up-a-city?lang=eng) (pp. 402-403).

Other examples of healings by Joseph Smith could be cited; this is the most famous one.

--

**Mary Fielding Smith and the healed ox**

I'm included this one because it's a classic of church history. Mary Fielding Smith (sister-in-law to church founder Joseph Smith) traveled west by wagon with the majority of church members in 1848, after her husband Hyrum and brother-in-law Joseph Smith were martyred and the church was expelled from Illinois.

During the trek west one of her oxen "Old Buck" took ill and the company captain indicated he would die. Mary called two elders of the church, who administered to the ox, which proceeded to jump up and carry on pulling the wagon.  See a written summary of the event [here](https://history.churchofjesuschrist.org/overlandtravel/sources/5524/joseph-f-smith-how-one-widow-mary-fielding-smith-crossed-the-plains-young-womans-journal-february-1919-165-171). Note that this occurred in the presence of people who had worked with animals their entire lives.

--

**Lorenzo Snow raised Ella Jensen from the dead**

In March of 1891, apostle Lorenzo Snow raised his niece Ella Jensen from the dead. She had died of scarlet fever, as noted by multiple individuals present, including a doctor. She reported experiences in the afterlife, after which she was called back to life.

While in the afterlife she learned of the death of a relative (present there) who had pre-deceased her by a few hours--she had not been told of his death prior to her own.

Ella went on to live for decades after being brought back to life.

For a brief summary see section entitled "He Brought a Young Woman Back to Life" in chapter 5 of [this book](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/manual/presidents-of-the-church-student-manual/chapter-5?lang=eng) on Lorenzo Snow. A longer account is provided [here](http://www.ldsscriptureteachings.org/2016/12/13/ella-jensen-raised-from-the-dead-by-lorenzo-snow/).

--

**Matthew Cowley and the raising of the dead**

While serving as a missionary in New Zealand Matthew Cowley was present on multiple occasions when the dead & dying were healed.

On one of the occasions, the healing took place in a hospital, where a doctor had confirmed Vera [last name withheld] was on the point of dying of tuberculosis. Matthew Cowley and Vera's uncle administered to her and she was restored to full health.  Elder Cowley later reported: "The last time I was in New Zealand she was physically well from head to foot and had had her fifth child."

On another occasion, Matthew Cowley was present when a young man's dead body was being prepared for burial. The young man was blessed by priesthood authority, sat up, and said: “Send for the elders; I don’t feel very well.”

A summary of these experiences was provided by Elder Cowley (then an apostle of the church) in [this speech](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/2004/10/miracles?lang=eng) given on February 18, 1953, after returning to the United States. In it he also recounts multiple instances in which he restored sight to the blind.

--

**Other examples**

Many other examples could be cited. I have excluded events involving people still living out of respect for their privacy. I have excluded events involving me and my family because I consider them too personal to share.

--

**Conclusion**

Members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe in and expect that miracles can and do occur. But miracles come by faith, not the other way around.

We also believe that God expects us to make use of what He has already given us before demanding to be given more. As apostle Jeffrey R. Holland stated:

> If you had appendicitis, God would expect you to seek a priesthood
> blessing *and* get the best medical care available. (see [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2013/10/like-a-broken-vessel?lang=eng))

---

Disclaimer--my comments are the product of my own study and do not constitute official statements by The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints

Comment: Are the medical records go support any of this?

Comment: @Ken Graham I put a few relevant comments in the last paragraph of the section "doctrinal background".  These events do not have hospital paperwork associated with them (to my knowledge). Rather, they are based upon eyewitness testimony of those who were present, including witnesses with medical training.

Comment: All good! Appreciate your response.