# Are there publicly accessible before-and-after medical records validating a testimonial of miraculous healing?

Tags: miracles, resource-request, science, healing, healthcare

Let's say that a person testifies that they were miraculously healed of X. One way to validate their testimony is to have access to the medical records before and after the healing of X took place. Are there any such cases where the medical records have been made publicly accessible, e.g. on a website so that anyone may have direct access to them and see for themselves the medical evidence?

**Note**: this question is inspired by the article [Before-and-After Medical Records -
Are healing claims documented?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/testing-prayer/201207/and-after-medical-records)

---

**Closely related questions**

- [Are there or have there been Christian healing ministries that have documented healing cases with supporting medical records?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82583/50422)
- [How do believers in present-day miraculous healings respond to skeptics requesting thorough scientific medical documentation accessible worldwide?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90141/50422)
- [Have any healings during modern revivals been medically confirmed?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86934/50422)

Comment: I am sure there are some. But it requires looking into many many case to find them. Some people prefer privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably not...** I think you're going to run up against some legal/privacy issues if you want the medical records of people to be made public knowledge. On the other hand, doctors can often track down and examine the documentation firsthand, for example there is a group of researchers working on gathering medically verifiable data. You can find their total findings to date [here](https://www.globalmri.org/library/), although not every article is free to access. However, **two** specific, articles from different medical journals that examine medically documented cases are accessible in full [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0965229918313116?via%3Dihub), and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1550830720300926?via%3Dihub).